# how can i call a method of another class when one delegate is triggerred?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, object, communication

i have a mainViewController class and a wifi connection class in my project.
Main view controller class will initialize the wifi connection class(all network delegates and events).there is a delegate in wifi connection class which will work when a stream is came to our device.i need to call a mainViewController method named as "welcomeMessage" when my wifi class delegate is triggered.
can any one help me to do it or provide me some good way to do it...